# Improving the plotting time of a very complicated expression

Tags: plotting, replacement, performance-tuning

The quatity $R$ is defined by a complicated expression in terms of $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n$. Now each $a_i$ is a function of $x$, $a_i(x)$. I would like to know what is the most efficient way to substitute in R the expression for the $a$s and then plot it as a function of $x$. I am only interested in the plot.

For concreteness consider the following code:

```
With[{vecup = Table[(Abs[a[i]]^2 - 1)*If[ε^2 >= 2 i, 1, 0], {i, NN}], 
      vecdown = Table[(1 - 1/Abs[a[i]]^2)*If[ε^2 >= 2 i, 1, 0], {i,  NN}]}, 
  R = Abs[ψorbR]^2.vecup/(1 + Abs[ψorbT]^2.vecdown)];
v[n_] := Sqrt[1 - 2 n/ε^2];
a[i_] := -I Sqrt[(1 + Sign[i] v[Abs[i]])/(1 - Sign[i] v[Abs[i]])];
```

I would like to plot `R`. The vectors `ψorbR` and `ψorbT` are very large expressions, and as I increase `NN`, these vectors increase in size causing the expressions of their elements also to increase in size, eventually making `R` impossible to plot.

Are there efficient ways to do operations on large expressions such as R that will help in keeping the plotting time reasonable?

Comment: No code showing your attempt(s)?

Comment: This is a small step in the code I am doing. I could put this part of the code, but it depends on some other quantities that are not relevant for the question and it would be a bit cumbersome. I decided just to ask the essence of the problem I am facing. Schematically what i do is R= (something in terms of the a_i); then define a_i[x_]:= some function of x. Plot[R,{x,xmin,xmax}].

Comment: Well, there's the obvious approach: if you have `a1[x_] := (* stuff *)`, ... `an[x_] := (* stuff *)` and `R[a1_, a2_, ... an_] := (* stuff *)`, then you can do `Plot[R[a1[x], a2[x], ... an[x]], {x, xmin, xmax}]`.

Comment: This is basically what I did and is slower than what I would like. The problem is that R is a large expression.

Comment: I would wager that the slowness is due to the fact that your expression is complicated, not because of the method of definition. As I said, maybe you should post your code.

Comment: Depending on how many times you're doing the calculation, perhaps [`Compile`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Compile.html?q=Compile&lang=en) would help?

Comment: Are there typos in your code?  For instance, the period in `Abs[ψorbR]^2.vecup` is interpreted as a decimal point (`2.`) but the `Dot` product makes more sense here, so that `R` is a scalar function of `ε`.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Wow, that's a terrible bug. The OP most likely entered the `^2` as a superscript in the front end, which parses correctly as `Dot[Power[a, 2], b]`, but copies as ``Times[Power[a,2.`],b]``

Comment: @rm-rf Wow indeed, copying "As Plain Text" mis-interprets the period. Very insidious.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to make some assumptions/guesses based on the code:

- The `.` represents the `Dot` product.
- `ψorbR`, `ψorbT` are each a list/vector of complex numbers of length `NN`.
- Since `i` runs from 1 to `NN`, `Sign[i]` may be omitted.
- Since `a[i]` is evaluated only in `Abs[a[i]]` the `-I` factor may be omitted.
- Since the terms containing `a[i]` are multiplied by `0` if `ε^2 < 2i`, two things follow for the terms included (not multiplied by 0):  `0 < v[i] < 1`, and the `Sqrt[..]` in `a[i]` is real; hence the `Sqrt` cancels with the `^2` in `Abs[a[i]]^2`.

Aside from the above, I make two changes that speed things up: 1) Replace `v[i]`, `a[i]` by lists `v0`, `a0` and use `UnitStep` instead of `If[.., 1, 0]`.  I also wrap the function in `Compile`.

```
Block[{NN = 1000},
 SeedRandom[1];
 ψorbR = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, NN] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}, NN] I;
 ψorbT = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, NN] + RandomReal[{-1, 1}, NN] I;
 R2 = Compile[{{ε, _Real}, {ψorbR, _Complex, 1}, {ψ]orbT, _Complex, 1}},
   Module[{v2, v0, a0},
     v2 = 1 - 2 Range[Length[ψorbR]] / ε^2;
     v0 = Sqrt[v2 * UnitStep[v2]];
     a0 = (1 + v0) / (1 - v0);
     Abs[ψorbR]^2 . (a0 - 1) / (1 + Abs[ψorbT]^2 . (1 - 1/a0))
    ], RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"]
 ]
```

---

Comparison of timings on 100 function calls:

```
Do[R /. ε -> e, {e, 1., 1001, 10}]; // Timing
Do[R2[e, ψorbR, ψorbT], {e, 1., 1001, 10}]; // Timing
```

> ```
> {2.949274, Null}  
> {0.008294, Null}
> ```

Plotting it is reasonable fast:

```
Plot[R2[\[Epsilon], \[Psi]orbR, \[Psi]orbT], {\[Epsilon], 0, 50}] // Timing
```

[image: Timing and plot]

There are insignificant differences (due to round-off error).  Usually the relative error in this example is less than `10^-12`:

```
Table[(# - R2[e, \[Psi]orbR, \[Psi]orbT])/# &[R /. \[Epsilon] -> e] // Chop[#, 10^-12] &,
  {e, 2., 1002, 10}] // Tally
```

> ```
> {{0, 99}, {1.98163*10^-12, 1}, {1.91073*10^-11, 1}}
> ```

So if it's not exactly the function intended, at least it's an accurate representation of the posted `R`.

---

My interpretation of `R`:

```
With[{
  vecup = Table[(Abs[a[i]]^2 - 1) * If[ε^2 >= 2 i, 1, 0], {i, NN}], 
  vecdown = Table[(1 - 1/Abs[a[i]]^2) * If[ε^2 >= 2 i, 1, 0], {i, NN}]},
 R = Abs[ψorbR]^2 . vecup / (1 + Abs[ψorbT]^2 . vecdown)]
```

The functions `v` and `a` are the same.